# Ошибка проверки установленного Docker

Tags: docker

устанавливал по инструкции Docker CE: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

чтобы убедиться что всё работает, запустил образ hello world, как и предложено на сайте :

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

мне выдаёт сообщение:
*Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
1b930d010525: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:92695bc579f31df7a63da6922075d0666e565ceccad16b59c3374d2cf4e8e50e
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.
To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/
For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/*

пытался получить образ предложенной командой

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

он должен начать скачивать образ из репозитория, но выдает сообщение: 
*docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.*

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: 1. *Hello from Docker! This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly* — требуется перевод? 2. **sudo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вариант-1. запускать через sudo:

```
       sudo docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

вариант-2. добавить юзера в группу docker

```
       sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
       sudo reboot
```

и запускать без sudo:

```
       docker run -it ubuntu bash
```